# Is it possible to set Static Google map markers to different colors and labels as parameters in the url?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-maps-static-api

I am trying to set map markers to two different colors, one blue with the label A and one red with the label B. In the following URL you can see that the markers are named and colored for all markers, can this be done for each map marker individually?

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Williamsburg,Brooklyn,NY&zoom=13&size=400x400&
markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C11211%7C11206%7C11222&sensor=true_or_false
```

i was trying this:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Williamsburg,Brooklyn,NY&zoom=13&size=400x400&
marker=color:blue%7Clabel:A%markers=color:red%7Clabel:B%7C11211%7C11206%7C11222&sensor=true_or_false
```

But this is wrong, can this be done at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accomplished this by doing the following:

```
"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=300x270&amp;zoom=1
                    &amp;markers=color%3ablue|label%3aA|
                    0,0|&amp;markers=color%3agreen|label%3aB|0,0
                    &amp;sensor=false"
```

Valid link:

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=300x270&zoom=1&markers=color%3ablue|label%3aA|0,0|&markers=color%3agreen|label%3aB|0,0&sensor=false